# Core Data Entity Not Updating Data

Tags: ios, core-data

**I am trying to Update core data Entities with the below code :**

```
(void)home:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender


{

managedObjectContext = [appDel managedObjectContext];

NSError *error;

NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Data" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

[request setEntity:entity];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name=%@ and number=%@",self.name,[NSNumber numberWithInt:temp]]];


NSManagedObject *managedObject =[[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
managedObject = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] lastObject];

[managedObject setValue:self.name forKey:@"name"];
[managedObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.number] forKey:@"number"];

[managedObjectContext save:nil];
```

BOOL saved =  [managedObjectContext save:&error];

```
if (!saved)
{
    NSLog(@"Data Not Saved");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Data Saved");
}
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

Can anyone Tell me if i am doing anything wrong? I also tried This [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031288/coredatatableview-not-updating-when-saving-from-child-managedobjectcontext-and-p) But it didn't work.

Comment: Do you want to create a *new* object, or update an *existing* object? Your code is a mixture of both.

Comment: Update an existing Object.

Comment: Is there only a single "Data" object, and that should be updated?

Comment: I created Entity Named Data & there are two fields in it.
 Attribute (name,number)(string,integer 16)

Comment: changed code to this 

    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] lastObject];

And It worked,I forgot about insertIntoManagedObjectContext..

Thanks @MartinR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSManagedObject *managedObject =[[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

creates a *new* object. If you want to update an *existing* object then you should
execute only the fetch request, and update the fetched object.

Only if no (matching) object exists, then you would create it.